# Cannot Interact with SearchBar added as HeaderView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

I have added SearchController's searchbar to tableview controller's headerview but when I tap on the searchbar keyboard doesn't pop up. it feels like there is no user interaction. Following is the code used to add searchbar to uitableview.

```
  self.resultSearchController = ({
                let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
                controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
                controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
                controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
                controller.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
                    controller.searchBar.bounds = (self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.bounds)!
                    controller.definesPresentationContext = true
                    self.definesPresentationContext = true

                })
                return controller
            })()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add just this 5 lines of code in your `viewDidLoad` and give it a try

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```